# Aframe 1.4.1: assets loading event is never fired

Tags: aframe

I am bumping my project from Aframe v1.3 to v1.4.1 and realize that suddenly the loading screen is stuck until the timeout is reached, eventhough the assets are all loaded. Is that a known bug? I realized that the file loader has changed with the new version so might that be the issue?

Comment: Without code to run and debug will be hard for people to help you. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe Best of luck.

Comment: We think we found the bug and I created an issue on github. The code snippets are all there.

Answer (score 1):

Created an issue and PR on github, checkout out here to follow: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/5251